# Debugging a Nox App Player ( Android Emulator ) under windows

Tags: android, linux, debugging, kernel, emulation

I want to perform a kernel debugging of the NoxAppPlayer, i want to know how certain system services work, such as `KeyGuard.apk` as far as i understood i need a KGDB for that, i have a cygwin for windows, it has GDB. But it doesn't to seem to have options for kernel debugging.

Currently what i did, i tried to do that with IDA PRO, i attached it to NoxVMHandle.exe and tried to look for some stuff in memory, but failed.
I only can catch things like `send` `recv` this way, but actually i wanted to extract some TLS enctrypted traffic from system application. And it seems that encryption is done already inside the Android, as breakpoints like `SSL_Write` , `SSL_Read` never gets reached in Ida pro.

Is there way to debug android kernel under windows with KGDB analog?